# Struts <html:select> set selected option dynamically

Tags: jsp, struct, jsp-tags, taglib

In the following Struts tags code I need to change the selected value in the select, before the page is rendered depending on the value passed from the action. However I couldn't find a way to get the option values and manipulate them.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html"%>

<html:form action="searchMusic" method="POST">
   <html:select property="searchType">
      <html:option value="CLASSICAL">CLASSICAL</html:option>
      <html:option value="ROCK">ROCK</html:option>
   </html:select>
   <html:submit value="Search"/>
</html:form>
```

I have tried the following function, but it is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var viewRockOrClassical = '${viewRockOrClassical}';
    if (!isEmpty(viewRockOrClassical)) {
        var searchBy = document.getElementByName("searchType");
        if (viewRockOrClassical == "ROCK") {
            searchBy.value = "ROCK";
        }

    }

});

function isEmpty(str) {
    return (!str || 0 === str.length);
}
```

Error I am getting upon the page loading is

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

This is caused by the line "document.getElementByName("searchType")".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the property value in action class, since you are having the value in action itself.

```
formObject.searchType = value;
```

Hence it will show the selected value on page loading.

Comment: Yes. It works. Thanks. Have to set the form object to request. I'll post the answer with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Give the select tag an id="selectbox" and try this:

```
 var viewRockOrClassical = '${viewRockOrClassical}';
        if (!isEmpty(viewRockOrClassical)) {
            var searchBy = document.getElementByID("searchType").options;
            for(int i=0;i<searchBy.length;i++) {
                if (viewRockOrClassical == "ROCK") {
                    searchBy[i].value = "ROCK";
                }
            }   
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the values in Struts form dynamically. We can directly set the values to the associated Struts action form and forward to the JSP page which contains the form.

```
public ActionForward selectMusic(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    Object requestForMusicType = request.getParameter("requestForMusicType");

    if (requestForMusicType != null && "forRockMusic".equalsIgnoreCase((String) requestForMusicType)) {
        MusicTypeSearchForm musicTypeSearchForm = new MusicTypeSearchForm();
        musicTypeSearchForm.setSearchType("ROCK");
        request.setAttribute("musicTypeSearchForm", musicTypeSearchForm);
    }

    return mapping.findForward("searchForMusic");
}
```